# Can't install from USB on MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)

Tags: release-freya, usb-drive, macbook, macintosh

I have tried to install **Elementary OS Freya** using a USB drive on my **MacBook Pro** (*Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015*) but the laptop doesn't recognize the bootable USB.

Many times I thought it could the the drive, so I use another ones, and re-made several times the image with no luck. Non the laptop or the **Startup Disk** utility found the drive as bootable.

Today, I just tested the same USB Drive on another **Early 2015** and on a **Late 2013**.

For my surprise, the USB drive is ok and is working "fine" on the Late 2013, but it didn't work on the another Early 2015.

*What's going on with those models?*

Also, as you may have noticed, I wrote *fine* whiting quotes, this is because when I booted the OS the UI was completely broken (looking huge) so i couldn't even use the OS on the Late 2013.

Is the development team aware of this issues?

Comment: Not entirely sure on this one as I am not too familiar with Mac systems and their BIOs but you may need to disable UEFI booting. I know that I was able to boot into the USB and install the OS but when I would reboot it would go to a grub screen. In which matter I had to reboot from USB in legacy and everything worked fine. Im not adding as an answer as im not positive, however this COULD be the issue.

Comment: MacBooks use EFI by default, not just the Early 2015 so I think this shouldn't be the issue, must be something Apple did with Bootcamp 6, because now you don't have to use a USB drive to install Windows, you just need the iso and OS X will install the boot drivers in the HDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HiDPI displays (like the one in your retina Macbook) aren't yet supported by elementary OS. You won't have a good time trying to install on this hardware. As you've noticed, the installer especially doesn't really behave properly here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel, but, are you guys planning supporting these kind of displays, because the Retina Display is kind of old now, and I know Ubuntu already support them.

Comment: @DaveGomez Yes, it is something that we're actively working on :)